# Problem to fix a question with WindowFunction

Tags: sql, window-functions

For school, I have to answer the following question, using a window function.

For each year, for each month, for each product category, indicate the percentage of that month's turnover that was from the annual turnover of that category.

I tried to use the window function but it didnt work. Because i dont know how to use the over (partition by) function

```
select 
  catcode, 
  year(besteldatum) as jaar, 
  month(besteldatum) as maand, 
  sum(regelomzet) as omzet, 
  sum(regelomzet) / (
    select sum(regelomzet)
    from ##joinall t2
    where t2.catcode = t1.catcode 
      and year(t2.besteldatum) = year(t1.besteldatum)
    ) * 100 as perc
from ##joinall t1
group by catcode, year(besteldatum), month(besteldatum)
order by catcode, year(besteldatum), month(besteldatum)
```

Comment: "I tried to use window function..."  So where is it?

Comment: I deleted that part because it didnt work, and uses now a subquery but my teacher need to see the window function. I guess it would be between the sum(regelomzet and *100 perc. But im not sure

Comment: That's the point of this website.  You post your attempt (broken code), and we can try to help you fix the code.  There's no point in posting a working query.

Comment: select catcode, year(besteldatum) as jaar, month(besteldatum) as maand, (SUM(regelomzet) / SUM(regelomzet) OVER (PARITION BY catcode, year(besteldatum))) * 100 as perc
from ##joinall 
group by catcode, year(besteldatum), month(besteldatum)
order by catcode, year(besteldatum), month(besteldatum) But when I tried something like this I get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [window functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) there's a thing to realize about them.
They get processed after the GROUP BY.

Hence, it's possible to sum over a sum.

And the PARTITION BY in an OVER is kinda similar to GROUP BY.

```
SELECT 
  catcode, 
  year(besteldatum) as jaar, 
  month(besteldatum) as maand, 
  sum(regelomzet) as omzet,

  cast(
  (sum(regelomzet) /
    SUM(sum(regelomzet)) OVER (PARTITION BY catcode, year(besteldatum))) * 100
   as decimal(5,2)) as perc

FROM bestellingen t
GROUP BY catcode, year(besteldatum), month(besteldatum)
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Comment: Error: <SQL> 'SELECT 
  catcode, 
  year(besteldatum) as jaar, 
  month(besteldatum) as maand, 
  sum(regelomzet) as omzet,

  cast(
  (sum(regelomzet) /
    SUM(sum(regelomzet)) OVER (PARTITION BY catcode, year(besteldatum))) * 100
   as decimal(5,2)) as perc

FROM bestellingen t
GROUP BY catcode, year(besteldatum), month(besteldatum)
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42S02: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'bestellingen'. 
Failed to execute SQL chunk

Comment: my example uses a different table name.

Comment: Glad it helped :)  Btw, most of time the window functions aren't used in combination with normal aggregations.  So it was fun to see a challenge where it's actually useful.